# How close an electrode should be to the target neural tissue?

Tags: electrophysiology, experimental-neuroscience

Intracortical electrodes are used to record neural signals. How close an electrode should be to the target neural tissue to obtain sufficiently clean / usable or hi-fidelity signal?

Comment: What specific tissue?  Do you need recordings from single neurons or would recordings of aggregate signals from multiple neurons be okay?  If so, how many?  If not, do you just need the spike times or do you need the spike waveforms?  How often do the target neurons spike on average?  Do nearby neurons tend to fire synchronously?  All these questions will make enormous differences in the answer.

Comment: what kind of recording electrode are you using?  glass pipette?  single wire? multielectrode array?